# Filtering array based on value in deeply nested object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash

I have array with following structure:

```
var topics = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "topic title 1",
    "sub_categories": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "category title 1",
        "indicators": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "indicator 1",
            "sub_category_id": 1
          },
          {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "indicator 7 - foo",
            "sub_category_id": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "category title 6",
        "indicators": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "indicator 8",
            "sub_category_id": 6
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "topic title 2",
    "sub_categories": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "category 2",
        "indicators": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "indicator 2 - foo",
            "sub_category_id": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "category 4",
        "indicators": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "indicator 5",
            "sub_category_id": 4
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I need to get filtered array based on value of name property in indicators array, removing non-matched indicators and both topic and sub_categories with empty indicators. So for input of `foo`, result would be:

```
var topics = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "topic title 1",
    "sub_categories": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "category title 1",
        "indicators": [
          {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "indicator 7 - foo",
            "sub_category_id": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "topic title 2",
    "sub_categories": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "category 2",
        "indicators": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "indicator 2 - foo",
            "sub_category_id": 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I tried to use lodash methods based on other similar SO question but all examples either have only one level of nesting or same keys on all levels (ie. children). I would be fine with either getting back new array or mutating existing one.

Comment: is the indicator only in name or in all properties possible?

Comment: If you are reffering to "indicator" in name value that is only for the example purpose, name value can be anything. Hierarchy however, is always the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an ES6 solution based on `reduce`, `filter` and `Object.assign`:

```js
function filterTree(topics, find) {
    return topics.reduce(function (acc, topic) {
        const sub_categories = topic.sub_categories.reduce(function (acc, cat) {
            const indicators = cat.indicators.filter( ind => ind.name.includes(find) );
            return !indicators.length ? acc
                : acc.concat(Object.assign({}, cat, { indicators }));
        }, []);
        return !sub_categories.length ? acc
            : acc.concat(Object.assign({}, topic, { sub_categories })); 
    }, []);
}

// sample data
const topics = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "topic title 1",
    "sub_categories": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "category title 1",
        "indicators": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "indicator 1",
            "sub_category_id": 1
          },
          {
            "id": 7,
            "name": "indicator 7 - foo",
            "sub_category_id": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "category title 6",
        "indicators": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "name": "indicator 8",
            "sub_category_id": 6
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "topic title 2",
    "sub_categories": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "category 2",
        "indicators": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "indicator 2 - foo",
            "sub_category_id": 2
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "category 4",
        "indicators": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "indicator 5",
            "sub_category_id": 4
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
// Call the function
var res = filterTree(topics, 'foo');
// Output result
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Interesting, after a comment by the op I came up with an almost Identical solution. Nice use of object shorthand properties.

Answer (score 7):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach for filtering the given array, without hard wired properties.

```js
const deepFilter = (array, indicator) => {
    return array.filter(function iter(o) {                
        return Object.keys(o).some(k => {
            if (typeof o[k] === 'string' && o[k].includes(indicator)) {
                return true;
            }
            if (Array.isArray(o[k])) {
                o[k] = o[k].filter(iter);
                return o[k].length;
            }
        });
    });
}

const topics = [{ id: 1, name: "topic title 1", sub_categories: [{ id: 1, name: "category title 1", indicators: [{ id: 1, name: "indicator 1", sub_category_id: 1 }, { id: 7, name: "indicator 7 - foo", sub_category_id: 1 }] }, { id: 6, name: "category title 6", indicators: [{ id: 8, name: "indicator 8", sub_category_id: 6 }] }] }, { id: 2, name: "topic title 2", sub_categories: [{ id: 2, name: "category 2", indicators: [{ id: 2, name: "indicator 2 - foo", sub_category_id: 2 }] }, { id: 4, name: "category 4", indicators: [{ id: 5, name: "indicator 5", sub_category_id: 4 }] }] }];

console.log(deepFilter(topics, 'foo'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Elegant solution! Thanks

Comment: Can you explain how this function works? I'm confused.

Comment: Okay, I understand it a bit better now. How can you adapt this to ES6?

Comment: Haha, lastly, how would you adapt this to the case where you're filtering an object, not an array of objects?

Comment: @NicScozzaro, it depends on the object.

Comment: @NinaScholz, instead of filtering the array of objects, my case is like filtering just the first object in the array in the provided example. But I'd prefer not to "hack" it by wrapping my object with brackets to make it an array and then taking the 0th element of the returned array so that I get an object as the return result (which I'm doing currently).

Comment: @NicScozzaro, great, if it works. if you have a question, please as a new one.

Comment: wow @NinaScholz, you asked me Create a new Question for nested array solution and I found this elegant answer of yours again :) Cheers mate

Answer (score 4):

This can pretty much all be done with ES 5 array methods (no library or polyfill needed for IE 9+):

```
var passed = topics.filter(function(x) {
  return x.subcategories.some(function(y) {
    return y.indicators.some(function(z) {
      return Boolean(z.name.match(/foo/));
    });
  });
});
```

While this is total one-off code, the situation is perhaps too complicated for an easily digestible general-purpose solution (although I'd love to see someone prove me wrong).

### UPDATE

After taking a closer look at the output you will need to use `reduce` instead of filter:

```
var passed = topics.reduce((acc, x) => {
  var hasfoo = x.subcategories.reduce((accum, y) => {
    var ls = y.indicators.filter(z => z.name.match(/foo/));
    if (ls.length) {
      accum.push(Object.assign({}, y, {indicators: ls}));
    }
    return accum;
  }, []);

  if (hasfoo.length) {
    acc.push(Object.assign({}, x, {subcategories: hasfoo}));
  }

  return acc;
}, []);
```

Astute readers will note the recursive pattern here. Abstracting that out is left as an exercise, I'm tapped out. `Object.assign` will need to be polyfilled for old browsers (trivial though).

Comment: Thank you for quick response but your solution returns everything under topic that contains matched indicator so I would still get back subcategories that contain indicator lists with no matches.

Comment: @TeoDragovic updated answer. Also see trinicot's, almost exact same as my updated.

Answer (score 2):

this will also modify existing `topics`

```
var result = topics.filter(top => 
    (top.sub_categories = top.sub_categories.filter(cat => 
        (cat.indicators = cat.indicators.filter(i => i.name.match(/foo/))).length)
    ).length
);
```

Example

```js
var topics = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "topic title 1",
  "sub_categories": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "category title 1",
    "indicators": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "indicator 1",
      "sub_category_id": 1
    }, {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "indicator 7 - foo",
      "sub_category_id": 1
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "category title 6",
    "indicators": [{
      "id": 8,
      "name": "indicator 8",
      "sub_category_id": 6
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "topic title 2",
  "sub_categories": [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "category 2",
    "indicators": [{
      "id": 2,
      "name": "indicator 2 - foo",
      "sub_category_id": 2
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "category 4",
    "indicators": [{
      "id": 5,
      "name": "indicator 5",
      "sub_category_id": 4
    }]
  }]
}];


var result = topics.filter(top => (top.sub_categories = top.sub_categories.filter(cat => (cat.indicators = cat.indicators.filter(i => i.name.match(/foo/))).length)).length);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more implementation.

```
        topics.forEach(function(topic, indexTopic, indexTopicArray) { 
                topic.sub_categories.forEach(function(subCat, indexsubCat, arraysubCat) { 
                         subCat.indicators = subCat.indicators.filter(indic => indic.name.includes("foo"));    
                         if(subCat.indicators.length === 0) { 
                                indexTopicArray[indexTopic].sub_categories.splice(indexsubCat, 1); 
    }})});
    console.log(topics);
```

Complete Code.

```js
var topics = [
  {
"id": 1,
"name": "topic title 1",
"sub_categories": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "category title 1",
    "indicators": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "indicator 1",
        "sub_category_id": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "indicator 7 - foo",
        "sub_category_id": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "category title 6",
    "indicators": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "indicator 8",
        "sub_category_id": 6
      }
    ]
  }
]
  },
  {
"id": 2,
"name": "topic title 2",
"sub_categories": [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "category 2",
    "indicators": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "indicator 2 - foo",
        "sub_category_id": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "category 4",
    "indicators": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "indicator 5",
        "sub_category_id": 4
      }
    ]
  }
]
  }
];


topics.forEach(function(topic, indexTopic, indexTopicArray) { 
             topic.sub_categories.forEach(function(subCat, indexsubCat, arraysubCat) { 
            subCat.indicators = subCat.indicators.filter(indic => indic.name.includes("foo")); 
            if(subCat.indicators.length === 0) { 
              indexTopicArray[indexTopic].sub_categories.splice(indexsubCat, 1); 
}})});
console.log(topics);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [_.filterDeep](https://deepdash.io/#filterdeep) from `deepdash` extension for `lodash`:

```
var endsWith = 'foo';
var foundFoo = _.filterDeep(
  obj,
  function(value, key) {
    return _.endsWith(value.name, endsWith);
  },
  { tree: { children: ['sub_categories', 'indicators'] } }
);
```

Here is a [full test](https://github.com/YuriGor/deepdash/blob/566add94b6d07defe9f9f4442f8f618b23a668d7/test/stackoverflow.js#L273) for your case